# How to show dynamic caption from a row of items where each item is 4 cell apart?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet like this :

[image]

And I have a user form which will dynamically add labels based on data I have in a column or row. The issue is that if its all aligned one by one, then I am able to generate dynamic labels. But I need to generate the first row of this sheet. So my labels will be A,B,C,D,E etc

This is my code :

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
     Me.ComboBox1.RowSource = "Sheet1!C8:C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

     number = Range("E1").Value
     Dim lblL1 As Control
     Dim cell As Range
           Dim Rng As Range
    For i = 1 To number
        Set lblL1 = Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
        With lblL1
        .Name = "lbl" & i
        .Height = 20
        .Width = 50
        .Left = 20
        .Top = 20 * i * 1
        End With

    Next i


    Set Rng = Range("O6", "ED6") 
'This is what I added to achieve this. But I am getting the last one displayed and not others
         For Each cell In Rng.Cells
            If cell.Value <> vbNullString Then
            With lblL1
            .Caption = cell.Value
            End With
            End If

        Next cell



    End Sub
```

If the items in the row/column are adjacent then I can use something like this :

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 Me.ComboBox1.RowSource = "Sheet1!C8:C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 number = Range("E1").Value
 Dim lblL1 As Control
 Dim cell As Range
       Dim Rng As Range
For i = 1 To number
    Set lblL1 = Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
    With lblL1
.Caption = "Label”" & i
    .Name = "lbl" & i
    .Height = 20
    .Width = 50
    .Left = 20
    .Top = 20 * i * 1
    End With

Next i
Dim q As Long
For q = 1 To number
 Controls("lbl" & q) = Cells(6, q).Value
Next q

End Sub
```

This is what I tried which gives me the last item in that row only :

```
 For Each cell In Rng.Cells
                If cell.Value <> vbNullString Then
                With lblL1
                .Caption = cell.Value
                End With
                End If

            Next cell
```

What has to be done to show all data in that row as each label (one by one) dynamically. Here each data is 3 cells apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without reading all your code, I'm trying to approach this from a logical point of view. You could

- create an array, then loop through all the cells in the row and add each cell with content to the array
- if the pattern is known, use OFFSET to get the values of the cells
- change the data layout so each column has the label in row 1 and the respective values for that category in the cells below.

The last approach would make most sense, because it tackles the issue from a data architecture point of view instead of building workarounds for bad data layouts.

Comment: If I replace  .Caption = cell.Value with say, Me.ListBox1.AddItem cell.Value , then it will populate everything avoiding the white spaces into the listbox